# Mod Rewrite, Unexpected Results

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2

We are trying to redirect everything from one domain to another with the following

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://www.example2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

When we visit http://www.example.com/v2sc

We are being redirected to http://www.example2.comv2sc

We would like to be redirected to http://www.example2.com/v2sc considering www.example2.comv2sc is not a valid hostname

Any ideas on how we can accomplish this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're using a .htaccess file for this. In [that context](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteContext) the leading slash is not present in `%{REQUEST_URI}` so it's up to you to put it back in.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.example.com
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example2.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
```

Please also note that solutions like this should be used only if you cannot edit the main server configuration file. Doing so would allow you to use a [cleaner combination](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/CanonicalHostNames) of vhosts and Redirect directives that would run much more quickly.